# OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty when renaming multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, rename

I tried to rename multiple files within a directory (deleting quotation marks), but encountered the following error message `OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty`.

Environment:
Python 3.5;
OS: High Sierra

The code:

```
import os
path = '/Users/Documents/'

for each in os.listdir(path):
    new_name = each.strip("\"\"")
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, each), os.path.join(path, new_name))
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the error pops out because there are multiple files with the same name. Deleting those duplicated files solves the problem.